# How to create a table in an Aspose.words Word template?

Tags: aspose.words

What's the best/easiest way to create a data table using Aspose.words templating engine? I know one way is to use the API to build the table. I am interested in knowing how to do it using a MS Word (.docx) file (or a .dot) file. An example snippet would be really helpful.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Also check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

The best an easiest way to create or fill table with data is Mail Merge with Regions. Please flow the [link](https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/About+Mail+Merge#AboutMailMerge-MailMergewithRegionsExplained) to learn more about this feature and this [link](https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/How+to+Execute+Mail+Merge) to learn how to fill template with data using mail merge.

Disclosure: I work at Aspose.Words team.